# Separate a string in two after replacing a character

Tags: java, android

This time I have an easy problem, I guess...
I'm new to Java/Android, sorry.

I have the following string:

```
String Column = Product_One_60;
String ColumnTwo = Column.replace("_"," ");
```

This gives me this:

```
//ColumnTwo = Product One 60
```

So far so good, then I need to get two strings like these:

```
String Product = Product One;
String Content = 60;
```

What do I have to do to get that?

Comment: I thought `Product_One_60` was a variable, string literals are surrounded by double quotes like `"_"`.

Comment: Please follow java naming conventions - variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I cannot believe it really works. Not as you wrote it.

Comment: I'm sorry for all errors. I'm new in this.
I'll consider all your advices (rules). Please help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a working translation of your original idea:

```
String Column = "Product_One_60";
String[] parts = Column.split("_"); 

String Product = parts[0] + " " + parts[1]; // "Product One"
String Content = parts[2];                  // "60"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string split function. It will split a string into pieces stored in a String array. The delimiter used is a specific character in the String so you would have to replace the "_" with the string you want to use to break up the String.

For example: (Assuming you use the "&" as the delimiter)

```
String product = "Product_One&60";
String array = product.split("&");

System.out.print(array[0]);//"Product_One"
System.out.print(array[1]);//"60"
```